# pdflatex of individual PDF images already containing pdfmark information

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, matlab

I'm using pdflatex to generate a document from hundreds of single-page PDF images.  (The images are originally in Postscript but I use Ghostscript to convert them to PDF prior to running pdflatex).  The Postscript images are actually Matlab/Simulink block diagrams which have a structure and hierarchy..

I'd like to add references/hyperlinks to these block diagrams so the reader can navigate through the document by clicking part of the block diagrams.

I can analyse the postscript images and gather cords for each block.  [Using Ghostscript I can add hyperlinks to individual PDFs at these cords.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663409/creating-a-pdf-hyperlink-with-postscript)  What I don't know is how do individual PDF images then get merged in pdflatex to allow the references to be updated.  What URI should I use when adding the hyperlink.  Should I use a hypertarget (anchor) on the target page?

Comment: As far as I know, PDF included with `\includegraphics` lose the links.

Comment: @egreg: Yes. AFAIK ConTeXt mkIV can keep them.

Comment: Heiko Oberdiek's `pax` might be able to help.

Comment: As I'm calculating the pdfmark annotations anyway, could they be added to the TeX source instead?  Kind of like an image map..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible using pdflatex.

Switching to dvips and the \includegraphics command honors any pdfmark information contained in the input postscript image.